# how to get access to db fields when using cron

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cron

I have a scenario where I need to calculate interview time and if interview is going to start in 15 mins, I need to send an sms (for now I kept console).

So I am using cron for that but I need to get time of interview from the `profiles` collection and calculate `currentDate - toi < = 15` then print that to console.

**Code**:

```
   var cronJob = cron.job("*/15 * * * * *", function() {
    // perform operation e.g. GET request http.get() etc.
    Profiles.find(function(err, profiless) {
        var date = new Date();
        if (date - "profiless.combinedDate" <= 15)
            console.info('cron job completed');
    });
    console.info('cron job completed');
});
```

cronJob.start();

mongodb schema:

```
var ProfilesSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
uniqueId: String,
toi: Date,
typeOfInterview: String,
presentRound: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
}
```

});
above is the schema for profile collection where i am trying to calculate `systemDate-toi<=15` and then send sms accordingly for each profile.
Here I am getting an error like `toi not defined`-  `toi` is a field in mongodb where time of interview for each candidate is stored.

I have no idea how to get access to the field. I am using express js framework and mongoose driver. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `toi` ? Can't see definition of toi here. post more relevant code

Comment: You need to execute the MongoDB find command to get the "toi" field from MongoDB collection and then you can compare with date object. If you can provide the Mongodb collection data structure, I can provide you the query to get the data.

Comment: @notionquest have updated my question